# Como selecionar todas as colunas de uma linha?

Tags: java, mysql, sql

É possível selecionar todas as colunas de uma linha?

Eu tenho uma função em que, na tela onde o usuário será criado, é feita uma validação no primeiro campo digitado para constatar se a *ID* do usuário que eu estou tentando cadastrar no banco já existe.

Isso, a fim de que, o usuário não tenha que esperar preencher *30* campos e só ao clicar em criar, ser avisado de que o usuário em questão já existe.

Quando eu digitar o *ID* do usuário já existente e passar para o próximo campo, aparece um `confirmDialog` onde a *Sim* busca TODOS os dados do usuário já cadastrado no banco e mostra em tela, e a opção *Não* continua na mesma tela.

Com isso, eu preciso que, todas as colunas do *ID* digitado no primeiro campo, sejam exibidas.

```
cd_telefone|cd_cliente  |nr_ddd |nr_telefone
    1      | 30         | 11    |2562-2791
    2      | 30         | 11    |2562-2791
    3      | 31         | 13    |8888-8888
    4      | 30         | 11    |5555-5555
    5      | 30         | 13    |9623-54002
    6      | 30         | 11    |1111-2525
```

Exemplo: Eu digitei a *ID* 3 - sou avisado que essa *id* já existe e clico em *Sim* no `confirmdialog` porque quero me certificar de que esse usuário é o mesmo que estou tentando cadastrar.

Quando clico em *Sim*, um `SELECT` vai buscar no *DB* e exibe dentro dos respectivos campos:

```
3 , 31, 13, 8888-8888.
```

Isso é possível?  Se alguém puder me mostrar como se faz eu agradeço.

Eu tentei várias coisas. Dentre elas:

```
SELECT * FROM userinfo WHERE ID '"+IdTextField+"';
```

E várias outras formas, mas nenhuma surtiu o efeito que eu preciso.

PS: Estou tentando exibir os dados pelo `SELECT`, na mesma tela em que digitei o *ID* existente.

Comment: você não quis dizer: SELECT * FROM userinfo WHERE ID =  '"+IdTextField+"' ? Seria melhor você editar sua pergunta e fazer uma explicação melhor, ela está muito confusa.

Comment: Você quer verificar durante o preenchimento do formulário já existe algum usuário com alguma das informações que estão sendo digitadas assim que o usuário muda de campo? É isso?

Comment: Poste o código que não deu certo.

Comment: É exatamente o que o @ErlonCharles disse!

Comment: Você precisa apenas recuperar todas as colunas de uma tupla listada ou alguma coisa mais? Se alguma coisa mais, fale de forma concreta, o que? Se for apenas recuperar as colunas, veja a resposta abaixo, por favor.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

SOLUÇÃO!

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.table.*;
import java.sql.*;

public class Estudos extends JFrame{
  public Estudos(){
    super("JTable");

    final DefaultTableModel modelo = new DefaultTableModel();

    // constrói a tabela
    JTable tabela = new JTable(modelo);

    // Cria duas colunas
    modelo.addColumn("Código");
    modelo.addColumn("Nome");
    modelo.addColumn("Senha");
    modelo.addColumn("Idade");

    // exibe os dados da tabela MySQL
    try{
      Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
      Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/usuarios?user=root&password=Schindler88");

      // procedimentos para obter os dados de uma tabela
      Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
      String query = "SELECT * FROM USUARIOS";
      ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);

      while(rs.next()){ 
        int id = rs.getInt("CODIGO");
        String nome = rs.getString("NOME");
        String senha = rs.getString("SENHA");
        int idade = rs.getInt("IDADE");
        modelo.addRow(new Object[]{new Integer(id), nome, senha, new Integer(idade)});
      }

      // fim procedimento para obter os dados
      } 
      catch(SQLException ex){
           System.out.println("SQLException: " + ex.getMessage());
           System.out.println("SQLState: " + ex.getSQLState());
           System.out.println("VendorError: " + ex.getErrorCode());
      }
      catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println("Problemas ao tentar conectar com o banco de dados");    
    }
    // fim MySQL

    tabela.setPreferredScrollableViewportSize(new Dimension(350, 50));

    Container c = getContentPane();
    c.setLayout(new FlowLayout());

    JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(tabela);
    c.add(scrollPane);

    setSize(400, 300);
    setVisible(true);
  }

  public static void main(String args[]){
    Estudos app = new Estudos();
    app.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Sim, é possível selecionar todas as colunas de uma linha, usando o **`*`** mesmo, o wildcard para todas as colunas da relação, aparentemente você está com problemas na montagem da query.

Por `SELECT * FROM userinfo WHERE ID '"+IdTextField+"';` dá a entender que você está concatenando os campos para filtro na query. Dê preferência no uso de [PreparedStatement](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html)s.

Então, baseando na definição da sua tabela, com os campos `cd_telefone`, `cd_cliente`, `nr_ddd`, `nr_telefone` você pode fazer algo assim:

```
final String sql = "SELECT * FROM userinfo WHERE cd_cliente = ?;";
final String format = "cd_telefone: %s | cd_cliente: %d | nr_ddd: %d | nr_telefone: %s";

try (final Connection conn = /* obtenha a conexão de alguma forma */; final PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement(sql)) {
    ps.setLong(1, 30); // o '30' é o filtro, no nosso exemplo, para 'cd_cliente'

    try (final ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery()) {
        while (rs.next()) {
            final Long cdTelefone = rs.getLong("cd_telefone");
            final Long cdCliente = rs.getLong("cd_cliente");
            final Integer nrDDD = rs.getInt("nr_ddd");
            final String nrTelefone = rs.getString("nr_telefone");
            System.out.println(String.format(format, cdTelefone, cdCliente, nrDDD, nrTelefone));
        }
    }
}
```

Considerando os dados que você informou na pergunta, este exemplo irá gerar a seguinte saída:

```
cd_telefone: 1 | cd_cliente: 30 | nr_ddd: 11 | nr_telefone: 2562-2791
cd_telefone: 2 | cd_cliente: 30 | nr_ddd: 11 | nr_telefone: 2562-2791
cd_telefone: 4 | cd_cliente: 30 | nr_ddd: 11 | nr_telefone: 5555-5555
cd_telefone: 5 | cd_cliente: 30 | nr_ddd: 13 | nr_telefone: 9623-54002
cd_telefone: 6 | cd_cliente: 30 | nr_ddd: 11 | nr_telefone: 1111-2525
```

Para gerar o resultado para o ID(`cd_telefone`) 3 ou caso a definição da sua tabela seja diferente, só alterar o nome das colunas no exemplo.

Obs.: só use o **`*`** quando realmente necessário e em tabelas com poucas colunas, usar em casos que você não precisa informação de todas as colunas traz problemas como os descritos [aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3639861/why-is-select-considered-harmful).